# Trim whitespace in included sourcecode snippet

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Is there any way to trim the beginning indentation white spaces in a included source code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the `indent` attribute in your include directive, see [Indent included content](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/include-with-indent/). If you include code from a `snippet.src` file, it will look something like this:

```
include::snippet.src[indent=0]
```

or

```
[source,indent=0]
----
include::snippet.src[]
----
```